# Django count of related objects with conditions

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to get the count of related objects with a condition:

```
Item.objects.annotate(count_subitems=Count('subitems'))
```

Subitem has a `created_at` column, which I need to use for filtering the count (greater than a date, less than a date or between dates).

How can I do this with the Django ORM?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum, Case, When, IntegerField

Item.objects.annotate(
    count_subitems=Sum(
        Case(
            When(subitems__created_at__lte=datetime.now(), then=1)
        ),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter the `Items` that have at least one `subitem` matching, and then count all the `subitems` for that `Item`:

```
(Item.objects
    .filter(subitems__created_at__lte=datetime.now())
    .annotate(count_subitems=Count('subitems')))
```

Comment: This will filter the `Item`s that have at least one subitem matching, and then count all the subitems for that `Item`.